# "Table doesn't exist in engine" after moving tables from one VPS to another

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin, debian

I have two VPS's running right now. One, which I will refer to as the "old" server, runs on **Debian 7** and gives this output for `mysql --version`:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

The other, which I will refer to as the "new" server, is running on a brand new installation of **Debian 8**, and gives this output:

`mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.20-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

I am trying to move my databases & tables from the old server to the new server.  I thought that I could do this by simply copying the `/var/lib/mysql/` directory from the old server and overwriting the same directory on the new server. However after doing this, I now receive this error in phpMyAdmin on the new server when I click on any of the tables or databases:

`#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine`

However I can clearly see that it exists:

[image]

Is there a solution to this? I'm not sure what I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: See the https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-9362?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: Had the same error. Stopping and then starting MySQL Server again resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506495/2364405

Except with these changes:

- On Step 5, I did not find `create_tables.sql`, but I found `create_tables.sql.gz` instead. I used WinSCP and downloaded this file, then imported it into phpMyAdmin (This takes care of steps 6 and 7).
- On Step 8, I only changed the username/password. My tables have TWO underscores (`pma__bookmark` for example), so I did not change them to one underscore.

Somehow this allowed me to use phpMyAdmin again with no errors. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can copy files from one server to the next to move your database. To do this, you must make sure that both instances of your DB are stopped. I also recommend using **rsync** to copy your database files. In addition to making sure that both database servers are stopped before moving the files, you will most likely need to change the ownership of your files. `sudo chown --recursive mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` before starting your new instance.

There are other options available to move your database. If your database isn't terribly large, **mysqldump** is probably the most simple. I have attached the documentation for **mysqldump** below as provided by MariaDB, as you are using MariaDB.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqldump/

Another option to consider, a bit more complex but a little more flexible for size, would be Percona's **xtrabackup**.

https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup

Comment: Also note, before trying the first option, go ahead and clear out the mysql directory on your new server before moving the files again.

Comment: rsync made no difference :( I cleared it out and made sure mysql was stopped on both servers first. I'll try mysqldump

Comment: Did you change the ownership of the files before starting on the second server? 

Being that you replied in 23 minutes, I'd bet that mysqldump will go rather quickly for you. 

try something like this. `mysqldump -u <user> -p --routines <database name> > dbdump.sql`

copy that to your new server
restore with 

`mysql -u <user> -p < dbdump.sql`

Comment: I did make sure they had the proper permissions before starting mysql back up. `mysqldump` didn't work either. The original way that I moved the sql files over was by backing them up into a tar file with permissions, sending it to the new server, unpacking, and using `cp -av` to copy them over with permissions. Also my databases are pretty tiny :P

Comment: An idea I had was to upgrade the old server to use the same version of MariaDB, then transfer the databases over. Would that do any good? Is there any incompatibility with MySQL and MariaDB?

Comment: Hmm, what error did you get with your mysqldump?
I'd imagine that once you've copied the files over, if you are unable to use the database with the copied files, that mysqldump wouldn't work on the restore until you had a full working instance of mysql. With the correct files being present, but mysql not recognizing them and being able to use them, the instance would be considered "corrupt". 

I've had this same trouble when I first became an admin, and I found that I was missing a step in the shutdown, copying dir, chown, start process. 

Mind sending errors and screenshot of new server dir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27179/discussion-between-nathan-and-mitch-talmadge).

Answer (score 2):

If you are just moving your DB from one folder to another folder, but your InnoDB tables no longer work, because they can't be found and the error message "Table does not exist in the engine" is displayed, then these pair of SQL statements can be as quick as helpful:

```
ALTER TABLE __yourtable_name__ DISCARD TABLESPACE ;

ALTER TABLE __yourtable_name__ IMPORT TABLESPACE ;
```

In pratice, the `.IDB` file is detached from `.FRM` file and then bound again, so that table contents turn into readable.

It worked in my case. Hope yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error after moving a mysqldump backup to a new machine, and doing some updates on the database I've deleted a unique index which had a key for an foreign constraint.

I did realize It was a Foreign Key Error using: **show engine innodb status**.

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2019-07-23 10:43:05 0x7f68a4255700 Error in foreign key constraint of table lhprovedorinfo/NOTAFISCAL:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
```

After that, I'v disabled the Foreign Key Checks with: set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Then dropped the foreign key and recreated it, in order to mysql create the necessary indexes. And the my table went back to life.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same - but moved from docker hosted on Windows 10 to a docker on Debian 10.9 - both having the /var/lib/mysql docker-mapped to a host directory.

If I move from docker on Windows to docker on another Windows machine there is no error.

I therefore suspected the different ways of handling case sensitivity on Windows and Linux. Inspecting the files in /var/lib/mysql I noticed that my 'File' table had a File.frm and a file.idb file. I tried to rename file.ibd to File.ibd to no avail but renaming both to lowercase makes the table readable again !!

In Windows docker defaults are
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables where Variable_name like 'lower%';

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | ON    |
| lower_case_table_names | 2     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

but in Linux docker the defaults are

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables where Variable_name like 'lower%';

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |
| lower_case_table_names | 0     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

which kind of explains :-)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_file_system

If you had different settings for lower case on your systems it could explain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked:

- I removed stray ***table***.frm,***table***.idb files from /var/lib/mysql/***database***
- drop ***table***
- create ***table*** (structure taken from a healthy table - show create table ***table***)
- if necessary re-import ***table*** from backup

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. I had installed a new OS on my machine. So I copied my Xampp folder then after installing the OS and copying back the files I got the "can;t find table in engine problem"
Deleting all the contents in the mysql folder then copying everything in the mysql folder from the old xampp worked like charm.

Answer (score -2):

Check that the copied files does have the proper user:group (e.g. mysql:mysql).

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything beyond what's already in the [current top-voted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111631/116653).